# Can I get EventAggregator Subscribe Message without view, viewmodel in prism?

Tags: wpf, module, prism

I'm trying to make a module in a prism project. The module doesn't have UI(View, ViewModel). I want the module has working EventAggregator event handlers.

Is there any way?

Comment: `I want the module has` - who is `the module`? it's initializer? or a service that's implemented in the module?

Comment: I will make a service in the module. I have some sample module codes that others made. They all have views and view models. So I wonder it is possible to make service module without view, viewmodels.

Comment: First of all I'm new in prisim.

May be my question is wrong.
Can I use "EventAggregator.GetEvent<>.Subscribe()" without View, Viewmodel?

I want to use broadcast messgae event and eventhandler with EventAggreagator.
And I need some services without UI. The services also need to use broadcat message evnet.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder it is possible to make service module without view, viewmodels?

Of course, it is. A module is just a late-bound, post-deployment-exchangeable collection of code. It can contain anything, be it views, view models, services, dtos...

> I want the module has working EventAggregator event handlers.

... most of those can have dependencies injected because they're resolved from the container. I.e. they can use the event aggregator.

If you have services that are "on their own" (i.e. like a windows service, but in-process) or that need to be initialized early, you can resolve the service in `OnInitialized` and start it/initialize it.